# How to give rights to user on server to use programs

Tags: linux, permissions

I installed a bunch of applications via SSH on a Debian Wheezy server. Now I want to give one extra developer rights to use one folder.

I added her to a new group "myappdevs" and gave the group right to read and write the directory. When I login as the new user and check the programs for:

```
ruby -v
```

I see an old version returned. And for

```
rails -v
```

and

```
bundle
```

I get the errors `[program] : command not found`. For `Vim` it did work, but I had to copy my own Vim profile to the home directory of the new user for it to work.

I am new to setting up permissions and access. How can I give the new user access to `ruby`, `bundle` and `rails`?

Comment: Sounds like you need to adjust `$PATH`.

Comment: Hi @Patrick. To what? Same as root? :) Okay I did that and the problem is solved...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `chmod 777 /path/to/kppp` you could do,

```
setfacl -R -m user:username:rx /path/to/kppp
```

Instead if you need to provide access to a particular group, you could do,

```
setfacl -m g:somegroup:rwx /path/to/kppp
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Patrick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4358/patrick) said in the comments I just needed to adjust the $PATH variable of the new user.

What I did was logging in as root, copied the result from `echo $PATH`. Then I logged in as the new user and did:

```
PATH=$PATH:[copy paste the $PATH result of root)
```

All programs now work. Problem solved. */edit*, problem not solved since it was not a permanent change.

I had to put `PATH = "[copy paste the $PATH result of root]"; export PATH` in the `~./profile` file.